# Inserting Child Lists into SQL with Dapper

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper

I have the following 2 tables:

```
public class TestA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TestB> Test { get; set; }
}

public class TestB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TestAId { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is I can access all the TestB records related to TestA from my TestA object. What I am trying to figure out is how do I insert into both Test A and TestB, especially if TestB has multiple rows related to Test A. Here is what I tried:

```
var data = new TestA
{
    Name = "ABC",
    Id = 1,
    Test = new List<TestB>
    {
        new TestB() { Id = 1, TestAId = 1},
        new TestB() {Id = 2, TestAId = 1},
        new TestB() {Id = 3, TestAId = 1}
    }
};

var query = "INSERT INTO TestA(Id, Name) VALUES(@Id, @Name) INSERT INTO TestB(Id, TestAId) VALUES(@Test.TestB.Id, @Test.TestB.TestAId)";

using (var con = conn)
{
    con.Execute(query, data);
}
```

I know that we can give dapper a list and it is smart enough to enumerate that list and insert individual records, but how do I accomplish the same thing if that list is child of an object? I tried making my values also be `@Test.Id, @Test.TestAId` but it had exact same error.

> The member  of type Test.TestB cannot be used as a parameter value

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
var data = new TestA
{
    Name = "ABC",
    Id = 1,
    Test = new List<TestB>
    {
        new TestB() { Id = 1, TestAId = 1},
        new TestB() {Id = 2, TestAId = 1},
        new TestB() {Id = 3, TestAId = 1}
    }
};

var query = "INSERT INTO TestA(Id, Name) VALUES(@Id, @Name) INSERT INTO TestB(Id, TestAId) VALUES(@Test.TestB.Id, @Test.TestB.TestAId)";

using (var con = conn)
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO TestA(Id, Name) VALUES(@Id, @Name)";
    con.Execute(query, new { Id = data.Id, Name = data.Name });


    foreach (var item in data.Test)
    {
        string processQuery = "INSERT INTO TestB(Id, TestAId) VALUES (@Id, @TestAId )";        
        connection.Execute(processQuery, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out if there is a way to let Dapper handle the whole thing. It just seems impossible that it can't. Also instead of looping, I could just do `conn.Execute(processQuery, data.Test);` It is smart enough to take a list and generate the insert queries and run them.